# JavaLang No Such Method Error Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

im trying to create a simple app on Xamarin Forms but as soon as i try to run the app a few seconds into compiling the app enters break mode and shows me an error saying 'Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError' and i already tried debugging step by step and i cant find anything
[Break Mode Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi5t5.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cleaning the bin and obj folders usually helps in such situations

Comment: @FreakyAli i already tried that and the error persist 

No static method checkBuilderRequirement(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)V in class Ldagger/internal/Preconditions; or its super classes

Comment: Try to install the latest Xamarin.Google.Dagger NuGet package into my Xamarin.Android  project.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT That actually worked, but now when i execute the app i get a Firebase Exception i never got before, saying Firebase.Database.FirebaseException: 'Exception occured while processing the request.

Comment: Where do you use Firebase in your project?

Comment: Hi @LeoZhu-MSFT, please check a [DEMO](https://mega.nz/file/j49ECRhK#AUtneJNiAlk1Wn-yRQFFE6bpkV5gXyEFMDwEbzNlbhQ) on the link